# Android Invalid Map API Key

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a MapView going in an Android app.

I've seen many articles telling me how to get the debug.keystore fingerprint, however when I get mine and put it in online i'm told it is invalid.
Something that I noticed is that when I get the fingerprint, it has 20 different hex numbers, whereas the example key to enter has only 16.
I shortened mine (removed the last 4) and it worked.

However, I put this key in my code and when I load the activity screen I see the grid, my marker and the zoom controls, but no map. Everywhere I look says this is a problem with the key. I'm fine with that, but I need some help in getting the fingerprint then.

**EDIT
Something that I just noticed is that it is giving me the fingerprint as SHA1 rather than MD5. So how do I switch that up? The keyalg parameter is set to RSA, so it should defualt to MD5...

Comment: what command are you typing to produce the md5 fingerprint?

Comment: keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android > debug_fingerprint.txt
<br>
I know the addition of the "> debug_fingerprint.txt" isn't necessary but I get the same output if I don't put that.

Comment: Something that I just noticed is that it is giving me the fingerprint as SHA1 rather than MD5. So how do I switch that up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that you have JDK 7. JDK 7 seems to be returning the SHA1 finger print. If you want the MD5 has, throw a `-v` in there.

`keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey...(etc)`

it'll return both SHA1 and MD5. Use the MD5.

Comment: The -v switch is not listed in the official documentation. You saved my day.

Comment: Hello otra... i am facing the problem... but i generated the 6 months before., at that time it was working, i was able to view the map with overlays.....but now., only those overlays are only viewable., map is not loading.... is it a problem of maps API key ??? Help me